# Blank output after declaring a procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to determine why eID is not returning anything during its output. The procedure and declaration are below.

The specific issue is  "dbms_output.put_line('Information for employee #'|| eID);

I am expecting it to return the eID entered. So in the example below I entered '1' so I am expecting the output to show '1' as well.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_empDetails(
eID IN EMPLOYEES.employeeID%type,
fName OUT EMPLOYEES.firstName%type,
lName OUT EMPLOYEES.lastName%type,
dNAME OUT DEPARTMENTS.departmentNAME%type)
AS 
BEGIN
  SELECT firstName, lastName, departmentNAME 
    INTO fName, lName, dNAME
    FROM EMPLOYEES e
    JOIN DEPARTMENTS d
      ON e.departmentID = d.departmentID 
   WHERE e.employeeID = eID;
 EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Invalid employee ID');
END;
----
declare
eID number(20);
fname varchar(20); 
lname varchar(20);
deptName varchar(20);
begin
get_empDetails(1, fname,lname,deptName);
dbms_output.put_line('Information for employee #'|| eID);
dbms_output.put_line('Employee Full name : '||fname ||' '|| lname);
dbms_output.put_line('Department Name : '||deptName);
end;
---
Result: 
Statement processed.
Information for employee #
Employee Full name : Alice Smith
Department Name : Human Resources
```

Comment: `eid` is not an output parameter, so it is not going to be set by the stored procedure.

Comment: Having both the parameter and a variable with the same name is probably confusing the issue somewhat, too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in eiD as a parameter. you ware passing a literal value of 1.  Eid is null in that case.

```
declare
eID number(20);
fname varchar(20); 
lname varchar(20);
deptName varchar(20);
begin
get_empDetails(eID, fname,lname,deptName);
```

Comment: It is NULL in your case too :) Perhaps `eID number(20) := 1;` would do the job.